# Meteor.js calling a template.helpers function vs global variable

Tags: meteor

I am using [Reactive-table](https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/reactive-table) to display paginated data in my meteor.js app as shown below, yet data displayed in Reactive-table is dependent on on specific user event (Selecting client, project, date range and clicking on the submit button). So I was wondering if it is possible to trigger template.helpers >> myCollection function from the 'submit form' event? OR is it better to define a global variable to store data returned from user query based on the user (client, project, date range selection) then make this global variable the return from the myCollection function?

I have tried researching how to call .helpers function from an template.events event but couldn't find any information. So any help on which approach is better and if calling the .events function is better then how to do that, will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Below is the code I have in my app:

```
Template.detailedreport.rendered = function() {
     Session.set("dreport_customer", "");
     Session.set("dreport_project", "");
     Session.set("dreport_startDate", new Date());
     Session.set("dreport_endDate", new Date());

   $('.set-start-date').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        defaultDate: new Date()
   });
   $('.set-end-date').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        defaultDate: new Date()
   });  

  $('.set-start-date').on("dp.change",function (e) {
       Session.set("dreport_startDate", $('.set-start-date').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString());
    });
    $('.set-end-date').on("dp.change",function (e) {
        Session.set("dreport_endDate", $('.set-end-date').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString());
    });
};

Template.detailedreport.helpers({
    customerslist: function() {
       return Customers.find({}, {sort:{name: -1}});       
    },
    projectslist: function() { 
       return Projects.find({customerid: Session.get("dreport_customer")}, {sort:{title: -1}});       
    },
    myCollection: function () {
      var now  = Session.get("dreport_startDate");
      var then = Session.get("dreport_endDate");
      var custID = Session.get("dreport_customer");
      var projID = Session.get("dreport_project");
          Meteor.call('logSummary', now, then, projID, custID, function(error, data){
            if(error)
              return alert(error.reason);
            return data;
          });        
      }
    },      
    settings: function () {
        return {
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            showFilter: true,
            showColumnToggles: false,
            fields: [
                { key: '0._id.day', label: 'Day' },
                { key: '0.totalhours', label: 'Hours Spent'}                           
            ]
        };
    }

});

Template.detailedreport.events({
   'submit form': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var now  = $('.set-start-date').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString();
      var then = $('.set-end-date').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString();
      var custID = $(e.target).find('[name=customer]').val();
      var projID = $(e.target).find('[name=project]').val();
      //Here is the problem as I am not sure how to refresh myCollection function in .helpers
   },  
   'change #customer': function(e){
        Session.set("dreport_project", "");
    Session.set("dreport_customer", e.currentTarget.value);
   },
   'change #project': function(e){
    Session.set("dreport_project", e.currentTarget.value);
   }  
});



Template:

    <div>
      {{> reactiveTable class="table table-bordered table-hover" collection=myCollection settings=settings}}
    </div>




Server:

Meteor.methods({
  logSummary: function(startDate, endDate, projid, custid){
    //Left without filtering based on date, proj, cust for testing only...
  return Storylog.find({});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template helpers are reactive, meaning that they will be recomputed if their dependencies change.  So all you need to do is update their dependencies and then the `myCollection` helper will be recomputed.

Replace your comment `// Here is the problem...` with:

```
Session.set('dreport_endDate', then);
Session.set('dreport_startDate', now);
Session.set('dreport_project', projID);
Session.set('dreport_customer', custID);
```